# How do you remove fire resistance potions from a player inventory?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying for over an hour to try to find a command that allows you to remove fire resistance potions from a players inventory. I have used it's ids (12 and 8259)

I have tried /clear @a fire_resistance_potion, potion 12, potion 8259, fire resistance, etc.

Comment: I added commands I tried @ExpertCoder14

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that you are using the Bedrock Edition the commands would be

```
/clear @a potion 12 64
```

and

```
/clear @a potion 13 64
```

Answer (score -1):

***(This answer is for 1.15.2)***

The best I could do is `/clear Sylar6281 minecraft:potion{Potion:"minecraft:fire_resistance"}`. It only removes regular fire resistance potions (no glowstone, redstone, gunpowder). I'm trying to use it to remove other types of fire resistance, but I couldn't do it. I used `/give` to find working potions, but all the `potion` tags I've tried other than `minecraft:fire_resistance` gave me unobtainable potions. But for regular, basic fire resistance potions, the command works just fine.